# Are secondary replicas essential in Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I am new to stateful services. I have a requirement to spread my data across my cluster using reliable collections.

This is fine.

The confusion I have is with secondary replicas. My system writes data to a database.

Looking at the documentation, secondary replicas are designed to hold state as well. However, they will never really be accurate as I don't want them to write to the database.

So are they actually needed in my situation? How can I use stateful services for just partitioning my data across the cluster without worrying about replicas? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: *my system writes data to a database*  -> I suppose you mean reliable collections with that? Otherwise you should use a stateless service

Comment: I have over 100000 items of data.  I want to spread this data across the cluster so that the load is spread evenly.  I have figured this out.  In my current model (not using scaling or reliable collections) data is received by the system then saved into a database for persistence purposes.  I am looking at keeping data in reliable collections and writing it to a database so that conventional queries can be used to get data

Comment: I would do that. Either use reliable collections or a database but not both. If you need in-memory access of the data in the db use a simple concurrent collection or redis cache for example.

Comment: Anyway, data you store in reliable collections are replicated so when the primary gets down a secondary can be promoted with all data intact. So yes, they are needed! But secondary's don't accept requests so they are purely there for data security of the reliable collection

Comment: I was trying to go for reliable collections as the data stays local to the cluster and I don’t know how redis works with concurrency. The database side is more because of having developers who are used to getting data from databases

Comment: ok so it looks like I dont need to worry!

Comment: Correct. But please, from my experience either have your developers understand reliable collections or stay away from it. Having to sync the reliable collections with a db seems like a big risk to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Reliable Collections as your primary storage, yes, the secondary replica is essential to keep your data replicated across different nodes and keep availability of your data in case of a node failure.

Because you are also adding the same data to a database, you don't have the same risk of loosing your data, but it would beneficial to keep the replicas in the cluster, because in case one node goes down with your data(that is very common during host updates and hardware failures), you would have to sync the database with the new services instances, and the sync might take too long when this data is too big, so your services will have to wait the synchronization finish before you start using it again, if you have the replicas already replicated on other nodes, the only process required in case of failure is elect a secondary to be the primary and continue the processing with smallest downtime possible.

In my opinion, what you are doing is just adding extra overhead to the process, because the performance you gain keeping the data in the nodes are lost when you have to write it back to the database, unless this is static data just for querying. Also, the complexity of keeping them in sync, you might face issues for example while saving it to the database and already wrote it to the Reliable Collection and Vice Versa, having to handle rollback on different storages or keep them out of  sync.

Maybe you could consider replace the stateful service for a stateless and adding a cache layer between your service and the database, where every call to get an item in the database you would check if it isnot yet in the cache, if not, get from the database and add to the cache, for the case you could use:

- InProcess cache via [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are using .Net;
- Azure Redis cache in the same region\zone of your cluster
- Redis cache in the same cluster as GuestExecutable(separate node)
- Redis cache as a sidecar, deployed alongside your services on same node

You can also have the partitioning concept of service fabric using stateless services, where each service would be responsible for a set of data, the first section of [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning) explains that.

Regarding your arguments, about using Redis: Redis is one of the most reliable cache solutions out there, I don't think concurrency will be an issue for you, it can also be deployed as part of your cluster as a GuestExecutble or as a Container(preferred).

Unless the DB+Cache is being a bottleneck for you current situation, 100000 items is almost nothing, and any DB system can handle that very well, I would recommend you stick with the DB solution only, because it is more mature and the internet is loaded with content covering the majority of the use cases. Adopting Reliable Collections will add complexity and maintenance to your solution that will not give much benefits on this scale.

Comment: I am desperately trying to avoid redis - a) because of not knowing how it deals with concurrency and b) because its another hop outside of the cluster.  I am interested in the idea of partitioning stateless services though.  All I really want to do initially is to spread my work around the cluster

Comment: In terms of the database I could probably lose that and maybe have a process that writes data to the database each night?

Comment: I've added extra info, please take a look. You could use MemoryCache instead of redis, but I still think you are adding extra overhead and complexity moving the data to the services, because the volume of data you have is very low to justify this design approach, a simple DB instance could handle this volume very well.

Comment: @DiegoMendes It really depends how you are accessing the data. If you need to query all 1M records, update them all, and save them back to db each time the user clicks a button then that may be a case for reliable collections. There are limitations like network speed that come in to play with use cases like this that no db can overcome. Sometimes the data needs to be co-located with the processing.